# Is there a reason `tolist()` can't operate on a list?

Tags: python-2.7

I often think it would be nice to have the following work even if the original object is a list... Is there a reason why this functionality is not implemented (in python 2.7)?

Example:

```
>>> a = [1,2,3,4]
>>> a.tolist()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'tolist'
```

Comment: Because `.tolist()` is a property of numpy arrays not Python's builtin list...? What would `.tolist()` do on a list anyway - return itself or a copy? If the former you just access `a` itself anyway and if the later... there's `list(a)` to take a shallow copy of any iterable anyway...

Comment: I would have liked it to return a copy, basically just so that if I want to ensure a bunch of objects are lists and not numpy arrays I don't have to remember which ones were lists to begin with! This is useful to me because I often store objects in a json file and numpy arrays are not serialisable, and just need a method to convert all those arrays to lists.